# Group array based on many values

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, ember.js, grouping

I want to group the following array of products:-

```
const array = [{date: "10 feb", from: "2", to: "10", name:"chair"},
               {date: "10 feb", from: "10", to: "22", name: "chair"}, 
               {date: "10 feb", from: "22", to: "31", name: "chair"}, 
               {date: "10 feb", from: "35", to: "40", name: "chair"}, 
               {date: "12 feb", from: "2", to: "10", name: "chair"}, 
               {date: "12 feb", from: "10", to: "20", name: "toy"}]
```

Such as if the date and name of consecutive product are similar and also "from" of 1st product is same as "to" of the next product then they should be grouped by taking "from" of 1st product and "to" of next product.

```
Result array = [{date: "10 feb", from: "2", to: "31", name:"chair"},
                {date: "10 feb", from: "35", to: "40", name: "chair"},
                {date: "12 feb", from: "2", to: "10", name: "chair"}, 
                {date: "12 feb", from: "10", to: "20", name: "toy"}]
```

Preferable solution using Foreach loop rather than for loop.

Comment: This logic is more of a reduction, rather than a grouping.

Comment: Also, please show any attempt that you have made to solve this issue yourself.  You are expected to have made an attempt that we can then help you debug.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users  Also review [ask]

Comment: @Taplar http://jsfiddle.net/sagarkataria45/62ehgpfz/10/
This doesn't give the results I want

Comment: Please review https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do for information about making an on site runnable snippet, rather than linking to an off site snippet resource.

Comment: @Taplar can you please answer the actual question please? I am a new developer i would more than appreciate help on this question

Comment: I'm am advising you on the practices that StackOverflow asks of people asking questions, as covered in the [ask].  Without a example of an attempt, we have no way of knowing if you have made any effort to solve it yourself.  With a snippet that is off site, that snippet can become broken over time, and makes the question useless.  Questions on StackOverflow are not only for your benefit, but for future readers.  Questions are expected to be written with this in mind.  That is why I am attempting to advise you on improving your question for these reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `reduce` function to achieve the desired result.

```js
var array = [{date: "10 feb", from: "2", to: "10", name:"chair"}, {date: "10 feb", from: "10", to: "22", name: "chair"}, {date: "10 feb", from: "22", to: "31", name: "chair"}, {date: "10 feb", from: "35", to: "40", name: "chair"}, {date: "12 feb", from: "2", to: "10", name: "chair"}, {date: "12 feb", from: "10", to: "20", name: "toy"}];

var result = array.reduce((acc, elem)=>{
   index = acc.findIndex(val=>val.to == elem.from && val.date == elem.date && val.name==elem.name);
   index == -1 ? acc.push(elem) : acc[index].to = elem.to
   return acc;
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

I hope this helps. Thanks!